# Get Current Context of Android App

Tags: android

I'm having issues getting the current context of my app.  I have an object, that I reference/use in multiple places.  When used anywhere in the app, it could return a KEY_STATUS_FAILED if the user's credentials have expired.  In that case, I would like to, from which ever page the user is currently at, re-direct them to the login screen to re-establish credentials.  I have tried several functions to get the base context with no success (currently using `getApplicationContext()` ).  All help is appreciated!

```
//In common execution thread, after reading return from HTTP Post call
int stat = Integer.parseInt(checker.getString("status"));

if(stat == KEY_STATUS_FAILED){
    Log.d("Process t", "Key Status Failed");
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogInPage.class);
    startActivity(i); //this never occurs
}
```

I am currently getting the log output that it has entered the Key Status Failed if-loop.  However, my application is not re-directing to `LogInPage.class`.  I'm sure this is something basic, and I'm just committing a boneheaded mistake, but I'm pretty new to this, so thank you all for the help.

Comment: How about your `Manifest` file? Did  you register `LogInPage` in `Manifest`

Comment: What's the type and supertype of the class in which this piece of code exists ?

Comment: log ur stat and see value,

Comment: Set breakpoints and try running apps in debugging mode to see whats happening.

Comment: It may be because you're not using the right context. Application context *should not* be used to start a new activity. If you have no choice, you must then start a new task. Cf https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/ -> Context Capabilities

Comment: this is a dumb question but did you try getBaseContext()

Answer (score 2):

You are providing Application Context which is not responsible for starting an activity. You need to use Activity Context to do so.

Try using :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, LogInPage.class);
startActivity(i);
```

or Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), LogInPage.class);

or try creating a global context variable in your activity class and use that or try this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(((YourActivity) getActivity()), LogInPage.class);
```